# Reading first lines of bz2 files in python

Tags: python, bz2

I am trying to extract 10'000 first lines from a bz2 file.

```
   import bz2       
   file = "file.bz2"
   file_10000 = "file.txt"

   output_file = codecs.open(file_10000,'w+','utf-8')

   source_file = bz2.open(file, "r")
   count = 0
   for line in source_file:
       count += 1
       if count < 10000:
           output_file.writerow(line)
```

But I get an error "'module' object has no attribute 'open'". Do you have any ideas? Or may be I could save 10'000 first lines to a txt file in some other way? I am on Windows.

Comment: Which version of python are you using? `bz2.open` is in python 3 not python 2. Try `bz2.BZ2File` instead.

Comment: I have python 2.7, with `bz2.BZ2File` I get the same error message

Comment: That's not possible. How do you use BZ2File and what error do you get?

Comment: `source_file = bz2.BZ2File(file, "r")` I've just replaces open with BZ2File

Comment: I'm as puzzled as @tjollans - since you replaced `open` with `BZ2File`, you shouldn't get an error with "open". Unless its in a different part of your code. Does my solution work for you? If not, can you add the full stack trace to your question?

Comment: Right after `import bz2` you could add `bz2.BZ2File` just to see if your module is corrupted.

Comment: Sorry, I've meant I get the same error "'module' object has no attribute" but of course this time with BZ2File "'module' object has no attribute 'BZ2File'"

Comment: if i write "from bz2 import BZ2File" I've get an error "cannot import name BZ2File"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a fully working example that includes writing and reading a test file that is much smaller than your 10000 lines. Its nice to have working examples in questions so we can test easily.

```
import bz2
import itertools
import codecs

file = "file.bz2"
file_10000 = "file.txt"

# write test file with 9 lines
with bz2.BZ2File(file, "w") as fp:
    fp.write('\n'.join('123456789'))

# the original script using BZ2File ... and 3 lines for test
# ...and fixing bugs:
#     1) it only writes 9999 instead of 10000
#     2) files don't do writerow
#     3) close the files

output_file = codecs.open(file_10000,'w+','utf-8')

source_file = bz2.BZ2File(file, "r")
count = 0
for line in source_file:
    count += 1
    if count <= 3:
       output_file.write(line)
source_file.close()
output_file.close()

# show what you got
print('---- Test 1 ----')
print(repr(open(file_10000).read()))
```

A more efficient way to do it is to break out of the `for` loop after reading the lines you want. you can even leverage iterators to thin up the code like so:

```
# a faster way to read first 3 lines
with bz2.BZ2File(file) as source_file,\
        codecs.open(file_10000,'w+','utf-8') as output_file:
    output_file.writelines(itertools.islice(source_file, 3))

# show what you got
print('---- Test 2 ----')
print(repr(open(file_10000).read()))
```

Answer (score 7):

This is definitely a simpler way of doing it than the other answer, but it would be an easy way to do so in both Python2/3. Also, it would short-circuit if you don't have >= 10,000 lines.

```
from bz2 import BZ2File as bzopen

# writing to a file
with bzopen("file.bz2", "w") as bzfout:
    for i in range(123456):
        bzfout.write(b"%i\n" % i)

# reading a bz2 archive
with bzopen("file.bz2", "r") as bzfin:
    """ Handle lines here """
    lines = []
    for i, line in enumerate(bzfin):
        if i == 10000: break
        lines.append(line.rstrip())

print(lines)
```

Comment: Since python 3 also has `BZ2File` I see no need to do the dual imports.

Comment: The `open` is wrapped with an `io.TextIOWrapper` object so you have more flexibility with encodings, etc... I prefer it to BZ2 file to begin with.

Comment: _"This is definitely a simpler way of doing it than the other answer,"_ are you referring to my answer? How is this simpler? It pulls all 10000 lines into memory and doesn't write an output file at all.

Comment: You don't really have more flexibility if you also want to maintain python 2 and 3 compatibility. It just seems more complicated to me!

Comment: @tdelaney you can easily write the file to another. That wasn't the point. The point was to show an easy, cross-version way of opening an archive... I don't expect him to read 10,000 lines into memory. The only reason it stays is the `lines` list. If he doesn't have that, it doesn't read it into memory.

Answer (score 2):

Just another variation.

```
import bz2

myfile =  'c:\\my_dir\\random.txt.bz2'
newfile = 'c:\\my_dir\\random_10000.txt'

stream = bz2.BZ2File(myfile)
with open(newfile, 'w') as f:
  for i in range(1,10000):
    f.write(stream.readline())
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo pip install backports.lzma
```